# After setting state elements are not rendered in the browser

Tags: reactjs, react-state-management, react-state

I am trying to fetch some data from an API and render it in my browser. My code is as below:

```
import React from 'react'
import {Col, Container, Row} from "react-bootstrap";
import {getTests} from "../services/getTests.setvice";
import TestRow from "../components/testRow.component";

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            testList: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount = async () => {
        const list = await getTests();
        this.setState({testList: [...list]});
    };


    render() {
        console.log(this.state.testList);
        return (
            <Container style={{maxWidth: '100%'}}>
                <Row>{this.testList ? this.testList.length : 0}</Row>
                <Row style={{height: 100}}>
                    <Col md={3}>{!this.testList ? <div>No test found</div> : this.testList.map((test) => {
                        return <TestRow>{test.attributes.name}</TestRow>
                    })}</Col>
                    <Col md={9}></Col>
                </Row>
            </Container>
        )
    }
}

export default HomeScreen;
```

The issue is that even though the list is printed successfully in the console. It is not being rendered on the browser.
Please help me identify what I am doing wrong. My console log is as in the screenshot below:
[image]

Comment: `this.testList` is supposed to be `this.state.testList` ?

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing this out. Don't know how I missed it. I think it will take some time to learn react with a angular mindset. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referring to `this.testList` in your `Col` component, instead of `this.state.testList`. `this.testList` doesn't exist, so it renders nothing.